Acess nginx ingress controller from another pc in the same network
Can some one help me with that?
I'm workin in one K8S cluster, created by kubeadm in V1.29.4, the cluster is running in bare-metal server, with centOS 7, in the same network as mine, i'm making the access to it via SSH, and controlling everything in my personal machine.
The cluster config:
server: https://10.3.192.2:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin

Previously I used the docker to manage my containers and when I used it, nginx as my reverse proxy, it was enough pass the IP from my server: 10.3.192.2 and the path to my browser if I can access, from my machine via the local network.
Now I deploy my applications and they are running, without any problem, using Nginx Ingress Controller to access them and make the paths to have access, as I don't have any load balance service, I'm using port-forward to expose my controller.
I added the host name in the file /etc/hosts to have access.
The host file:
#127.0.0.1   10.3.192.2
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1   physis-iot.com

The ingress manifest:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: portal-front
#  annotations:
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: physis-iot.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: portal-front-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /path-a
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: portaliot-front-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /selatiot/auth
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: selatiot-portal-backend-service
            port:
              number: 4001

The problem now:
I'm only having access through curl in ssh, that gets me the html file, but I want to have access in my machine, using the domain I set and being able to interact with my program, but when I try the browser response with "The website was not found". Can some one help me with that, please?
Any additional information, just ask!
I've already tried to set the domain in my local /etc/hosts pointing to IP 10.3.192.2, but still doesn't work.

Your hosts file needs to have the specific entry for 10.3.192.2. Assuming you can access 10.3.192.2 from your local machine.
Specifically in your hosts file:
10.3.192.2   physis-iot.com

This is assuming that ""The website was not found" is a 404 status code.
